# Animate UIView using swift 4.2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewanimation

Someone, please help me with this animation, When I click on X button the cardView move out form screen with 0.3 seconds after that card comes back it's an original position(that is center of the parent view) with fade animation. Same thing for right side when users click on the ✅ button the card should move right.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.cardView.frame.origin.x =  self.cardView.frame.minX - (self.cardView.frame.width + 100)
             self.cardView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle:-45)
        }) { (true) in
            self.cardView.center = self.view.center
            self.cardView.alpha = 0;
             self.cardView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                self.cardView.alpha = 1.0;
             }, completion: { (true) in

            })
        }
```

**Example of Image -**

[image: Sceenshot]

Comment: Show your code. You can’t expect blind diagnosis?

Comment: Please share your code, what have you done so far?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please be aware that this isn't a code writing service - read [ask] and [mcve] and update your question.

Comment: So what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: The animation isn't working smooth. Some time behave weirdly.

Comment: You did post some code, didn't you? If you don't mention the current behaviour or the code, how do we know where the problem is? Anyway, you should use `.pi / -4` instead of -45 for the rotation angle, because it's in radians.

Comment: What do you mean by "behave weirdly"?

Comment: Please check this video 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15VdwUKr7WGGnTFsw87HcyGlDfJUmSWft/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That looks normal to me. You seem to be tapping the button too quickly. What is your desired behaviour?

Comment: My desired behavior is when tapping the button the animation should working fine even I tapping the button too quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your main issue is that you don't call the [layoutIfNeeded()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded) function that actually makes the animation happens. check documentation. Try this function it should do what you want.

```
    func doAnimationAction(isTick: Bool) {

    let originToReturn = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.origin.x, y: self.cardView.frame.origin.y)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.cardView.alpha = 0.0
        if isTick {
            // Go left
            self.cardView.frame.origin.x =  0 - (self.cardView.frame.width * 1.5)

        } else {
            // Go right (you can change them)
            self.cardView.frame.origin.x =  self.view.frame.width + (self.cardView.frame.width * 1.5)
        }
        self.cardView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle:-45)
        self.cardView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.cardView.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { (finished) in
        // Here you can update the cardViewData
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.cardView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle:0)
            self.cardView.frame.origin =  originToReturn
            self.cardView.alpha = 1.0
            self.cardView.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.cardView.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { (finishedSecondAnimation) in

        })


    }


}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me Please check this video 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1leKXyQrZJEBUX0MTfdtLqaR6-5aV4qe1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok the issue it that I don't return the rotation, i will edit the answer

Comment: Try edited code, I added alpha also. You will probably have to change the rotation angle if he goes right to be first -45 and then 45.

Comment: What isn't working? Can you send me another video?

Comment: Here is another video
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M04rynZ8miIsZCrMEmBHoW64FvPjHpag/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Check again the issue is the way of how the rotation happens it should probably work. If not check if it works without the rotation code

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1joQs1tGDY8kPVyCdSgBh5JiqSihx3q7K/view?usp=sharing

Comment: check now I think it's fixed

Comment: Thank you so much brother :)

Comment: Your welcome! :-D